# Node.js Database Module with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js, require

To make my code more readable, I'm trying to move all database related code into a single file. and use Sequelize as ORM. I would like that this file, when included provide a ready to use Database. Tables schemas are also managed by Sequelize which is why I use the `sync()` method to create the tables on the first run. Unfortunately, when I run the application for the first time, I get an error that the table doesn't exist when using this code:

File: test.js

```
const database = require('./dbInit');

(async () => {

    await database.testTable.max('id').then((maxId) => {
        console.log(maxId);
    });

})();
```

File: dbInit.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/test');

const testTable = sequelize.import('testTable');

const database = {
    sequelize: sequelize,
    testTable: testTable,
};

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection to the database has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });

sequelize.sync();

module.exports = database;
```

File: testTable.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('testTable',
        {
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.BIGINT(19).UNSIGNED,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: false,
            }
        }
    );
};
```

When I run the code as is, without tables created, I can see from the logs that the query is run before the connection to the database is available:

```
> node .\test.js
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): SELECT max(`id`) AS `max` FROM `testTables` AS `testTable`;
Connection to the database has been established successfully.
(node:1572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'test.testtables' doesn't exist
```

I have found a way to make it work by adding this like, just before the call to the DB (in test.js before the `max('id')` call):

```
await database.sequelize.sync();
```

Is there any other way to have the dbInit module completely independent and not having to add this `sync()` call inside all other files which will require database connectivity?

I've looked for sync module loading but it doesn't seem an option yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of async behavior all of ops that You want to do:

1. Connect
2. Sync
3. Do DB operations

You've to make it following way:

put model files to: `db` folder as: `db/schemas/User.js`

and make module file for db: `db/index.js`

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/test');

const connect = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await sequelize.sync();

    console.log('Connection to the database has been established successfully.');
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    process.exit(-1);
  }
});

const model = name => database.models[name];

const User = sequelize.import('./schemas/User');

const database = {
    sequelize: sequelize,
    models: {User},
    connect,
    model
};

module.exports = database;
```

and in `test.js`:

```
const db = require('./db');

(async () => {
    await db.connect();

    const User = db.model('User');

    const id = await User.max('id');

    console.log(id);
})();
```

P.S. forget about examples that used in web apps when developer does not care when db will connect and when express app will listen on port. 
Your question is different - You want to do db query immediately, so You've to make sure connection and sync established successfully.

Comment: This is strange, now the logs look fine but I'm still getting ` 'test.testtables' doesn't exist` error - any idea?

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette read about Migrations http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html   tables must be created before of everything

Comment: Isn't that what `sync()` does? I was looking for a clean way to create tables dynamically. Seems like my issues is more a Node.js sync-async problem right now?

Comment: BTW look at this: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/usage.html  OPTIONS section, it has `sync: true`  it's enabled by default. Very strange that tables not creating.

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette try second option in my answer by passing `sync: {force: true}`

Comment: Yep, just tried, and getting the same result. I noticed something odd (might not be related) but Sequelize adds an 's' character when doing queries to my table: `Table 'test.testtables' doesn't exist` I also see this in the logs before the connection: `Executing (default): SELECT max(\`id\`) AS \`max\` FROM \`testtables\` AS \`testtable\`;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181403/discussion-between-nicolas-bouvrette-and-num8er).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow up my github repo [Sequelize-DemoApp](https://github.com/anurag0608/sequelize-DemoApp). It's a fully working full stack application made especially to demonstrate and understand Sequelize.js and it's integration with nodejs